# Image xy coordinates

Tags: java, android, xml, coordinates

I'm trying to animate some images in my Android app. To be specific I need to translate some png images from one location on the screen to another.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:fromXDelta="0%" 
 android:toXDelta="75%" 
 android:fromYDelta="0%"
 android:toYDelta="50%" 
 android:duration="3000" 
 android:zAdjustment="bottom" />
```

I got the above xml code from the net but it does not translate an image from one specific location of the screen to another specific location. How can I do that?

Comment: Try reading the documentation: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/view-animation.html

Answer (score 2):

Also try this :
http://obviam.net/index.php/moving-images-on-the-screen-with-androi/

Comment: While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.